# flutter firebase google-sign-in a pop in iOS is not showing my established google account

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-signin

In the iOS device when I used flutter firebase google-sign-in as a sign in method no pop is showing my list of google account I already used in that device.

Rather I need to type my email and password(or use face id or touch id to select key-store/password manager to put the email and password).

It is possible to do in React-Native(even in IOS) and I did it. What to do in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue already posted in the [official flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48602)